# Does Akka actors crash when futures throws an exception?

Tags: akka

I am seeing all my actors wrapped within RoundRobin Router crash when futures times out.

My actor is waiting for a result from futures and when it times i am seeing this behavior.

I am loosing few resources due to the crash as new set of actors are created.

Please suggest me how to handle the timeout better so that my actors wont crash?

Comment: Did you have some code to show us?

Comment: Why would you ever have to wait on the Future?

Comment: If your actors (from whom you are waiting results using ask pattern and futures) die due to an exception thrown inside them then you may catch these exceptions in your receive method and send an akka.actor.Status.Failure(cause) to the sender. And of course you should release your resources in finally statement if needed.

Comment: Sure thank you. So if i get an exception in recieving actor then i can catch the exceptions and send a failure notice back to sending actor. But would i be able to send the exception object to the sending actor so it can handle it accordingly.  Please suggest me.    
 Future<Object> future = Patterns.ask(adaptorRef, DayEvent,timeout);
 Calendar results =  (Calendar)Await.resultfuture,timeout.duration());